# how to create derive class from base class

Tags: c++

I have base class like this:

```
class Base{
public:
    virtual Base *createNew(){
        auto newItem = new Base();
        setNew(newItem);
        return newItem;
    };

    void setNew(Base *item){
        item->value = value;
    };

private:
    int value;
};
```

A number of derived classes are shown below, each of which has a `createNew` interface that returns a derived object.

```
class Derive1 : public Base{
    Derive1 *createNew(){
        auto newItem = new Derive1();
        setNew(newItem);
        return newItem;
    };

    void setNew(Derive1 *item){
        Base::setNew(item);
        item->value1 = value1;
    };

private:
    int value1;
};

class Derive2 : public Base{
    Derive2 *createNew(){
        auto newItem = new Derive2();
        setNew(newItem);
        return newItem;
    };

    void setNew(Derive2 *item){
        Base::setNew(item);
        item->value2 = value2;
    };

private:
    int value2;
};

class Derive3 : public Base{
    Derive3 *createNew(){
        auto newItem = new Derive3();
        setNew(newItem);
        return newItem;
    };

    void setNew(Derive3 *item){
        Base::setNew(item);
        item->value3 = value3;
    };

private:
    int value3;
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    std::list<Base *> list;
    list.push_back(new Derive1);
    list.push_back(new Derive2);
    list.push_back(new Derive3);
    list.push_back(new Derive2);
    list.push_back(new Derive1);

    std::list<Base *> listNew;
    for(auto item : list)
    {
        listNew.push_back(item->createNew());
    }
    ...
    //ignore the memory leak.
}
```

Is there any easy way to not write every `createNew` in the derived class, because they are similar, the only difference is the type. Do templates help?

Comment: Yes, you can achieve the same result with templates. Take inspiration from CRTP

Comment: Note with what you have right now, you are only calling `Base::createNew()`, you never called any derived versions.

Comment: Are you looking for cloning? `virtual Base* Clone() const { return new Base(*this); }` `virtual Derived1 Clone() const override { return new Derived1(*this); }`?

Comment: @Jarod42 s comment/answer is the way to go. Also: note your memory leak.

Comment: @Jarod42 Did you mean the overridden method to be `virtual Base* Clone() const override { return new Derived1(*this); }` or am I missing something?

Comment: @Rulle: C++ allows covariant return type (with pointer). So `Derived1* Clone() const override { return new Derived1(*this); }` would be correct (pointer is missing in first comment :/) returning `Base*` would also be correct.

Comment: @Jarod42 Cool - I admit this was new to me.

Comment: @Ranoiaetep forgot virtual, updated.

Comment: @Jarod42 cloning is not I am looking for, there is more logic than just copying fields.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Supposedly you want to use the Curiously Recurring Template Pattern (CRTP) for this. Here is an example where we introduce template class `BaseT` that inherits from `Base`. Note how each derived class inherits from `BaseT` passing itself as template parameter.

```
class Base {
public:
  virtual Base* createNew() = 0;
  virtual ~Base() {}
};

template <typename T>
class BaseT : public Base {
public:
  Base* createNew() override {
    return createDerived();
  }

  T* createDerived() {
    auto newItem = new T();
    setNew(newItem);
    return newItem;
  };

  void setNew(T* item){
    item->value = value;
    setNewDerived(item);
  };

  virtual void setNewDerived(T* item) {}
  virtual ~BaseT() {}
private:
  int value;
};

class Derive1 : public BaseT<Derive1> {
public:
  void setNewDerived(Derive1* item) override {
    item->value1 = value1;
  }
private:  
  int value1;
};

class Derive2 : public BaseT<Derive2> {
public:
    void setNewDerived(Derive2 *item) override {
        item->value2 = value2;
    }
private:
    int value2;
};

class Derive3 : public BaseT<Derive3> {
public:
  void setNewDerived(Derive3 *item) override {
    item->value3 = value3;
  };
private:
    int value3;
};
```

Is this what you are trying to do?

Comment: You should explain that with your solution, each "derived" class will have it's own "base" class (so it's not longer a common base type, so `std::list<Base *> list;` is not possible), and you should propose methods to overcome that.

Comment: @JHBonarius That is not a bad remark. Updated.

Comment: now fuse the baseT createderived into the derived class, and you're back to the cloning Jarod42 mentions in the comments. no CRTP required.

Comment: @JHBonarius Jarod42's approach is obviously the way to go if all you want is a member-by-member copy. But OP might want more logic than just copying fields. Who knows?

Comment: We did not know, as the OP did not specify it. And answering with a specific solution only works for a specified problem. It was just luck that you was thinking like the OP. Note, in C++23, the deducted `this` makes the whole CRTP pattern redundant (for 99% of the situations)

Comment: @JHBonarius: Exactly. You are spot on. My answer does not make any premature assumptions.

Comment: @Rulle I faced another problem, if Derive1 is inherited from Base, Derive2 is inherited from Derive1, Derive3 is inherited from Derive 2, do templates still work?

Comment: @BrettLi Not quite sure about how to do that. Are you sure that you need such a deep complicated inheritance hierarchy? Maybe there is a simpler solution for your problem: what problem are you actually trying to solve? Your code with names such as `Derive1`, `Derive2`, etc, does not reveal that.